# How do I navigate to my galaxy dashboard?

Tags: meteor, meteor-galaxy

I want to redeploy my project, but I lost the link that takes me to my galaxy dashboard to check my domain. (along with the redeployment command)

I tried to search for the link online but unfortunately I had no luck.

I didn't know I would face difficulties in finding the link, otherwise I would have saved it.

How can I find the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For us-east: https://galaxy.meteor.com/

For Europe: https://eu-west-1.galaxy.meteor.com/

See the [deploy guide](http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-guide.html)